# ssl3_get_record:wrong version number, ERPROTO Error when trying to connect using a proxy from an online list

Tags: node.js, http, https, proxy, request

I am trying to connect to a kahoot using a proxy from an online proxy list. The proxy is up, and works just fine so that isn't the problem, but I can't actually connect to it with a request from the code. I've tried using http, https, socks4 and socks5 proxies, all of them return the same error. Is there something I'm missing or need to add? The "options" and "proxy" is just an http request same as what you would see on https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

My code:

```js
        proxy: (options)=>{
          return Object.assign(options,{
            host: "51.104.203.226:33800",
          });
```

The full error:

```
{
  description: 'Request failed or timed out.',
  error: RequestError: write EPROTO 14200000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\queba\Desktop\kahootspam\node_modules\kahoot.js-latest\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:970:111)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at origin.emit (C:\Users\queba\Desktop\kahootspam\node_modules\kahoot.js-latest\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:43:20)
      at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
      at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16) {
    code: 'EPROTO',
    timings: {
      start: 1667511954639,
      socket: 1667511954641,
      lookup: 1667511954765,
      connect: 1667511954765,
      secureConnect: undefined,
      upload: 1667511954893,
      response: undefined,
      end: undefined,
      error: 1667511954894,
      abort: undefined,
      phases: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know if the proxy server is online for public use?